# Drools get first element of List in where clause

Tags: java, drools

Is it possible to get first element of list from **when** clause in Drools? 
If I don't know Object fields values inside the list and I want just to retrieve first element, how can I do this?

```
rule "TestRule1"
dialect "java"
when
    $c : Collection()
    $listCustObjs : ArrayList() from collect (CustomObject() from $c)

    $first : $listCustObjs.get(0) //<- something like this
    $otherObj : $first.other // <- take other element from first object from the list

then
   ...
end;
```

Comment: Did you try using ```$listCustObjs[0]```? That is what it seems to be done in drools documentation https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html at *5.8.3.3.8. List and Map access*

Comment: $first : $listCustObjs[0] will return [ERR 102] Line ... mismatched input '[' in rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the $listCustObjs object to List then only you will be able to use list methods. Casting is done in drools by using '#' operator. Check [here](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.15.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_inline_casts_and_coercion).

Also, you can directly use a statement like  `$first : $listCustObjs.get(0)`. In drools when all the computation or conditional check is done on Fact i.e object. So in your case, you can only get the value from $listCustObjs list when you will try to get it inside an object.